# Display Instafeed Images Using Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, instagram-api, masonry

I've implemented Instafeed on my studio's current website to display our Instagram feed in two rows of images. Ever since we allowed portrait and landscape photos to get fed through the API, we've been getting gaps in between the top and bottom row, since some images will be shorter than others.

We're currently trying to implement masonry in order to make the bottom row stack up against top and get rid of those awkward spaces but we're having trouble getting the entire thing to work.

In theory, this should do it:

The HTML:

```
<div id="instafeed">
<!-- width of .grid-sizer used for columnWidth -->
<div class="grid-sizer"></div>
<a><!--- these are the a attributes populated by Instafeed --></a>
<a><!--- these are the a attributes populated by Instafeed --></a>
<a><!--- these are the a attributes populated by Instafeed --></a>
...
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.grid-sizer {width:16%}
#instafeed {width:100%;margin-bottom:-.8%}
#instafeed a {width:16%;margin:0 0 .8% .8%;float:left}
#instafeed>:first-child,#instafeed>:nth-child(6n+7) {margin-left:0;clear:left;}
#instafeed a img {width:100%;height:auto;zoom:1;box-shadow:#000 0 0 0;opacity:1;-moz-transition:all .5s ease;-webkit-transition:all .5s ease;-o-transition:all .5s ease;transition:all .5s ease}
#instafeed a img:hover {zoom:1;opacity:.5}
```

The Javascript:

```
$('#instafeed').masonry({
// set itemSelector so .grid-sizer is not used in layout
itemSelector: '#instafeed a',
// use element for option
columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
percentPosition: true
})
```

That should theoretically work, but when I plug that in, not only do the photos not stack onto themselves, but one usually falls down to the second row, and the bottom of the site completely collapses.

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I have used masonry in the past and my items contained images, I have always had to combine it with the use of the imagesLoaded plugin.

What is most likely happening is that the masonry plugin is initialising the layout before the images have been loaded, and therefore the calculated position/height of each item is not accurate.

Hope this helps:
http://masonry.desandro.com/faq.html#how-do-i-fix-overlapping-item-elements